# Can fissile fuel be used in a conventional space rocket

Tags: nuclear-physics

Is there anyway to incorporate fissile fuel into rocket propulsion other than using it to heat the fuel? What if you dissolve the fissile material into molten salt, and then inject it into the combustion chamber of a nuclear thermal rocket, would the fissile material incinerate and react, creating more heat and propulsion, or would it just eject out of the exhaust, assuming it hits 4-5 thousand kelvin.

Comment: Similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_salt-water_rocket

Comment: Using atomic weapons as propulsion is feasible, although you probably don't want to do it near a planet you have to live on afterwards. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)

Comment: 5000K is peanuts to a nucleus - that will not cause fission (consider that in a nuclear weapon temperatures greater than the surface of the sun happen quite early in the process, well before any measurable yield).